# A-frame x and z object rotations are actually moving object position instead

Tags: aframe

I am trying to simply rotate an object in A-frame.
When I rotate it on the y-axis `rotation = "0 90 0"` it works fine.
But when I try and rotate it along the X or Z axes the object moves position along those axes instead.
For instance, with  `rotation = "10 0 0"` below it moves the head downwards without rotating it at all.

Here is the code in question:

```
<a-scene embedded arjs = 'trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;'>
<a-anchor hit-testing-enabled='true'>

    <a-entity
      scale="5 5 5"
      position="0 -8 -0"
      rotation = "10 0 0"
      obj-model="obj: url(models/free_head.obj);">
      </a-entity> 
</a-anchor>
    <a-camera-static/>
</a-scene>
```

Thanks for any insights you can give me

Comment: A glitch might help.. maybe the model is off centered?

Comment: Hi Piotr, thanks for helping.  I appreciate you popping in.  What you mean by a glitch? (I'm new at 3d modeling/AR)

Comment: I meant an [(minimal)example hosted on glitch](https://glitch.com/) so I or someone else could jump in and see whats going on :)